# rowspan issue in html

Tags: css, html

i am developing a report sheet for my solution. But i got problem in merging rows from table. i have attached image and some source code. In this image i want to merge yellow marked columns and make it single. Anyone please help me.

[image]

```css
.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.mytable-head {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.mytable-head td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.mytable-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.mytable-body td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
.mytable-footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.mytable-footer td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable mytable-body">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="6">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="6">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want to merge all cells in a non-rectangle area?

Comment: No, he wants to merge the columns of the non-rectangle area I think

Comment: Actually i just want to merge yellow marked part. It will be non rectangle.

Comment: you won't be able to merge all the yellow parts into one cell.  Tables don't work like that.  You can however, using rowspan=2, merge the first two cells in the first column since they span the same number of columns.  Using rowspan=3, you can merge 3,4 and 5 of the first column, etc., etc.

Comment: than how can i make this kind of design? What should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am able to make this design using `<Div>` tag. Code goes here:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>

<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:60%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:60%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>

<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>

<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:30%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>

<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>  
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>

<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
<div id="border" style="width:100%; height:30px;">
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black; float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:10%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
  <div style="width:40%; height:30px; border:1px solid black;  float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Div for tabular data? C‘mon.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution.

You can edit the **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3f1r44e/)** here

**Added code (CSS):**

```
tr>td:first-child{
  background: #ffe500;
}
tr>td{
  border: 1px solid #ffe500 !important; 
}
```

```css
.mytable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.mytable-head {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.mytable-head td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.mytable-body {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.mytable-body td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
.mytable-footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.mytable-footer td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
tr>td:first-child{
 background: #ffe500;
 border: 1px solid #ffe500;
}
tr>td{
 border: 1px solid #ffe500 !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable mytable-body">
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="6">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="6">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="3">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="4">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
    <td width="10%">Null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```